# How to prevent shell complete options for git commit-tree?

Tags: shell, git

When I'm completing `git commit` I would like it add a space at the end so I could enter the desired flags immediately. But, `commit-tree` is also an option, thus resulting in an annoying situation where I accidentally type: `git commit-m 'my message'`

How can I make the zsh completion ignore `commit-tree`?

EDIT: the completion is done by git-complete.

Comment: Does [autocomplete - ignore specific command from zsh completion - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533060/ignore-specific-command-from-zsh-completion) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill sadly, no. I forgot to mention, the completion is done by `git-complete`

Comment: So [edit] the question and make that clear. Your question asks about zsh completion not git-complete